# Is it possible to restore the certification after leaving the Sitecore company?

Tags: training-certification

So, developers get the internal certification when they start working for Sitecore. Is there any way to restore this certification after leaving the company? Or it is required to pass the certification again like an independent developer?

Comment: Are the internal certifications you mention the same as those that are publicly available?

Answer (score 1):

I would say that you should contact Sitecore support to change/update your email address, which you can use to log in. So just email address changes to login to SPN. I hope all your achievements and progress should be there. You can use the below link to contact the Sitecore support team.

```
[https://www.sitecore.com/company/contact-us][1]
```

Also, you can send an email to [globaltraining@sitecore.com](https://globaltraining@sitecore.com). So they can help you more with this.

Hope this helps.